# Using webapp2 i18n in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, internationalization, webapp2

I'm using webapp2 with webapp2_extras.i18n for a Google App Engine app.

I have a unit test script as described on the bottom here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting

The test script imports the models and does not include webapp2 handlers, because the target of the test is the business logic code, not the requests and responses. However, some of my models will call i18n functions like `format_currency` or `gettext` which will result in an error:

```
AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.
```

How can I initialize the i18n module without instantiating a webapp2 app and request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to mock your functions.

Example: I have a script called users that import i18n like this:

```
from webapp2_extras.i18n import gettext as _
```

So on my tests i mock the function like this:

```
from pswdless.model import PswdUserEmail, EmailUserArc
from pswdless.users import FindOrCreateUser
from pswdless import users

# mocking i18n
users._ = lambda s: s

#your tests bellow
```

You can use same trick with another functions.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (but for uri_for) and I ended up doing the following in my test :

```py
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
        [webapp2.Route('/', None, name='upload_handler')])

request = webapp2.Request({'SERVER_NAME':'test', 'SERVER_PORT':80,
    'wsgi.url_scheme':'http'})
request.app = app
app.set_globals(app=app, request=request)

# call function that uses uri_for('upload_handler')
```

I had to do trial and error to guess which environment variables have to be set in the request. Maybe you'll need to add more in order to call i18n.

Comment: This was helpful for unit test of code with: `i18n.get_i18n().set_locale()`

Comment: Thanks, I had to do this today, in 2017 :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite simple to mock i18n itself. I'd prefer this approach because Request and app are really not needed in unit-tests.

Here's a sample pytest fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_i18n(monkeypatch):

    class MockI18n:

        def set_locale(self, locale):
            pass

        def gettext(self, string, **variables):
            return string

    mock_i18n = MockI18n()

    def mock_get_i18n(factory=None, key=None, request=None):
        return mock_i18n

    from webapp2_extras import i18n
    monkeypatch.setattr(i18n, 'get_i18n', mock_get_i18n)

    yield
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking does seem to be the way to go here, but the other answers are not complete and/or more complicated than necessary.  Here is a simple mock that works for me.

```
=== my_module.py ===

from webapp2_extras.i18n import gettext as _

def f(x):
    return _(x)

=== test_my_module.py ===

import my_module

def _mock(x):
    return x

@mock.patch("my_module._", side_effect=_mock)
def test_f(self, foo):
    y = my_module.f("hello")
    self.assertEqual(y, "hello")
```